# Android - Setting animations to individual items in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I tried the following code to implement a slide bottom in (Google+ like) animation to my ListView items.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }

    convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Setting values to list items.

    convertView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom));
    convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return convertView;
}
```

The animation is working, the list items are pushed from bottom. But the problem is, the already available items at the top repeat the animation when I'm scrolling down and it looks really weird. And when I scroll up, the animation is repeated again. I'm pretty sure this is not the correct way to implement this animation. Is there a way to implement this without using any libraries?

EDIT : I extended from BaseAdapter to implement the adapter.

Comment: so Scrolling down animation works?? but not scrolling up?

Comment: It does work and that IS a problem. I only want scroll down animation to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the animation to work only when you scroll down you need to detect if you scroll down the listview and start the animation.

**sample:**

create a **global** instance of `lastPosition` in your **BaseAdapter**

```
int lastPosition;
```

After use that lastPosition to detect the if you are scrolling down or up

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }

    //if scroll down then play animation
    if(position <= lastPosition)
       convertView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom));

    convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    

    convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    lastPosition = position;

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it works if you change the `position <= lastPosition` to  `position >= lastPosition`.